# TPU VM profile tpu device in CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tpu

I create a Google TPU virtual machine for training my models.
Are there tools like `nvidia-smi` that could show tpu usage in CLI?

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 520.61.05    Driver Version: 520.61.05    CUDA Version: 11.8     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-PCIE...  On   | 00000000:1B:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   71C    P0   193W / 250W |  31128MiB / 32768MiB |     93%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:3D:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 51%   82C    P2   217W / 250W |  10671MiB / 11264MiB |     97%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:3E:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|134%   79C    P2   200W / 250W |   8015MiB / 11264MiB |     82%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Tesla V100-PCIE...  On   | 00000000:88:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   45C    P0    28W / 250W |      0MiB / 32768MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   4  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:B1:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 36%   60C    P2   103W / 250W |   9475MiB / 11264MiB |     25%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   5  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:B2:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|135%   84C    P2   230W / 250W |   8015MiB / 11264MiB |     94%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

The supposed output like this, it could tell me the memory and usage of TPUs.

I read the TPU user guide and found nothing like this.

Beside, `capture_tpu_profile --tpu=v2-8  --monitoring_level=2 --tpu_zone=<my_zone> --gcp_project <my_project_id>` return failed in VM.

```
2023-04-11 13:34:55.250537: I tensorflow/core/tpu/tpu_api_dlsym_initializer.cc:116] Libtpu path is: libtpu.so
[percpu.cc : 539] RAW: rseq syscall failed with errno 22 after membarrier sycall succeeded.
TensorFlow version 2.8.0 detected
Welcome to the Cloud TPU Profiler v2.4.0
I0411 13:35:28.692314 140515203357760 discovery.py:280] URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/tpu/v1/rest
I0411 13:35:28.908957 140515203357760 discovery.py:911] URL being requested: GET https://tpu.googleapis.com/v1/projects/tpu-cloud-381912/locations/us-central1-f/nodes/v2-8?alt=json
I0411 13:35:28.909139 140515203357760 transport.py:157] Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
Failed to find TPU <vm> in zone us-central1-f project <my_project_id>. You may use --tpu_zone and --gcp_project to specify the zone and project of your TPU.
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting with `capture_tpu_profile`? `capture_tpu_profile` will create a .tracetable file that is saved to a GCS bucket. You probably will also need to specify `logdir`. For other info on TPU usage, you could also look into Tensorboard.

Comment: Could you please provide some more details about the issue you're facing.

Comment: @gkroiz thx for your time.   I paste the error below.

Comment: @ArpitaShrivastava  not a big issue, just want to know the CLI  tool that TPU researchers used to monitor the TPU status.

Comment: It turns out that capture_tpu_profile only works for tpu nodes and not tpu vms. Based on whether you are using tensorflow/pytorch/jax I would suggest looking up their documentation on profiling tpus

Comment: check out https://pypi.org/project/jax-smi/ - "jax-smi is a tool for real-time inspection of the memory usage of a JAX process. It is similar to nvidia-smi for GPU, but works on multiple platforms including CPU, GPU and TPU."

Answer (score 0):

There is no google supported official implementation of `nvidia-smi` for TPUs, however there is an opensource code available that you can search for and use.

From the error message looks like zone and/or project name aren't specified correctly. Can you clarify how exactly you are running `capture_profile`? Did you replace `<my_zone>` and `<my_project_id>` with the values that you used to create your TPU VM? Looks like it got zone as us-central1-f but not the project id.

`capture_tpu_profile --tpu=v2-8  --monitoring_level=2 --tpu_zone=<my_zone> --gcp_project <my_project_id>`

Update: you might also find this tool helpful
https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/profile-tpu-vm#memory_viewer